# Having trouble with some computercraft/lua code

Tags: lua, computercraft

Hi I want my lua code in Computercraft to allow the user to turn the redstone signal on/off by right clicking on a monitor on top, but I can't get it to work.

```
monitor = peripheral.wrap("top")
monitor.clear()
monitor.setTextColor(colors.red)
monitor.setCursorPos(1, 1)
monitor.setTextScale(1)
monitor.write("Hello")

function rubber()
    monitor.setCursorPos(1, 2)
    monitor.clearLine()

    if rs.getOutput("right", true) then
        monitor.write("Rubber farm is on")
    elseif rs.getOutput("right", false) then
        monitor.write("Rubber farm is off")
    end

    local event = { os.pullEvent() }

    if event == "monitor_touch" then
        if rs.getOutput("right") == true then
            rs.setOutput("right", false)
        else
            rs.setOutput("right", true)
        end
    else
        write("test")
    end

    rubber()
end
```

Right now all it displays is 'hello' and I don't know how to fix it, anyone know how? Also I'm a beginner at Lua so I've probably made some pretty simple mistakes. Thanks

Comment: Please put the code in the post, rather than linking to it offsite :)

Comment: edited it so code is on site

Comment: Try indenting your code so you and can see what's going on

Comment: -1 code formattted illegibly, will cancel -1 when fixed

Comment: Notice how the `rubber` function is never called for the first time, made obvious by the indentation

Answer (score 2):

```
local event = { os.pullEvent() }
if event == "monitor_touch" then
```

[`os.pullEvent`](http://www.computercraft.info/wiki/Os.pullEvent) returns a tuple. In your code, you're packing this tuple into a table. That's fine, but you then compare that table to a string. Tables can't be equal to strings - they're a table. Either don't pack the tuple into a table, and keep the first return value (the type):

```
local event = os.pullEvent()
if event == "monitor_touch" then
```

Or extract the first element when comparing

```
local event = { os.pullEvent() }
if event[1] == "monitor_touch" then
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you wanted to have that function infinitly looping, but you have not called your function outside your function.... also you should look into using while loops

```
while true do
 //stuff here
end
```

just add

```
rubber()
```

to the last line after your last end tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function.
`rubber()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your function

```
function rubber()

  monitor.setCursorPos(1,1)

  monitor.clearLine()
end
```

The `end` is it you need to make this little word

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple fix, simply add rubber() after you finish the function rubber, cause while you have created the function rubber, you have not called for it to start yet.

Answer (score 0):

The "monitor_touch" event is what you should be using. Also, make sure the monitor you are using is an advanced monitor (the one with the yellow border).

If you need help in understanding the event, check out this page: http://computercraft.info/wiki/Monitor_touch_(event)